# No superscript or subscript greek letters with EB Garamond and mathspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, greek, mathspec, ebgaramond

When using the [EB Garamond](http://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond) font (v. 0.016) with XeLaTeX and mathspec, superscript and subscript greek letters in math mode do not appear in the pdf, though it compiles without error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){EB Garamond}

\begin{document}
Test
$\alpha^\alpha \beta_\beta$

\end{document}
```

[image: EB-Garamond]

The problem does not occur when using another font like [Crimson](https://github.com/skosch/Crimson).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Crimson}

\begin{document}
Test
$\alpha^\alpha \beta_\beta$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use `minimal` class.

Comment: This is what I get from your very input: [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qEnjy.png) As you see, the subscript and superscripts are there.

Comment: I am getting the same problem on two different computers with Ubuntu and Tex Live 2013

Comment: You probably need to update: TL 2013 is quite old in XeTeX/fontspec/opentype terms.

Comment: I could update, but I would like to know what is causing the problem

Comment: Does your version number not have a '+' i.e. `0.016+` rather than just `0.016`. If so, I'm guessing a font issue. At least, I can't reproduce the problem with (updated to final, frozen version) TeX Live 2013 either. [I have version 0.015 around, too, but not 0.016.)

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with both 0.015 and 0.016 (no '+').

Comment: Updating to TeXLive 2015 did not resolve the problem.

Comment: @egreg and @cfr, can you let us know exactly what versions of EB Garamond you're using? I'm getting this problem with `0.016`.

Comment: Search for garamond packages in Miktex console and install all of them (5 in total). That worked for me, even though i skipped the libre one