# Problem with math formula contains alpha subscript

Tags: math-operators, overleaf

I am newbie to latex. I would like to write a long math formula but I can't figure out why alpha subscript is missed out after compiling (Please find the attached picture). Here is how I write the formula in overleaf.

```
\begin{equation} 
  u = \sum_{I=1}^{N} N_I{(x)} \left[U_I + H(x)a_I + \sum_{\alpha{=1}}^{4}F_{\alpha}(x)b_I^{\alpha}\right]
\end{equation}
```

For further clarification, I can see that the following packages and fonts are used for writing the math in class file.

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{mathspec}

\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Proportional},SizeFeatures={{Size=-8, OpticalSize=8},{Size= 8-, OpticalSize=12}},]{EB Garamond}
\setmathrm{EB Garamond}
```

Please could someone point out what is wrong here? Many thanks for your help in advance!

[image]

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with the code, thought `\alpha{=1}` is a little strange. But it would help those tryi g to help you if (1) you post a full minimal example, not sniplets like this. Then it is a lot easier for others to test your code, and (2) state which engine you are using (presumably xelatex or lualatex).

Comment: Perhaps the font that you're using (which I don't have) doesn't include Greek letters?

Comment: Just wanted to point out a similar question (with no answer): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/265763/117534. Can you try compiling the code from there and let us know if you see the greek letters?

Comment: @daleif As mathspec does not really support lualatex it's probably xelatex. But maybe it would also help to try a free font.

Comment: @TeXnician see, I use neither engine, so did not know that.

Comment: I see the alphas: [click here for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOv9E.png)

Comment: @egreg could it be browser error (given the overleaf tag?)

Comment: @daleif Quite possible

Comment: Not just on Overleaf; same problem while compiling on Mac OS with TL 2017 and EB Garamond v0.016. In the meantime, the best solution I can find is to use `\mathrm{\alpha}` for superscripts/subscripts (MWE at https://www.overleaf.com/read/pyfxnmvzzdmh), if you want to stick to EB Garamond. See https://github.com/suchow/Dissertate/issues/66#issuecomment-283936075.

Comment: @LianTzeLim, thanks very much for your help. Please answer the question so that I can upvote you.

Comment: @Aryan Great, I've added it as an answer.

Comment: @Aryan I've deleted my answer as @egreg was able to get all the alphas without any problems at all with TL2017 on a Mac (though I have the same but they're not showing up in the PDF for me). So probably just treat the `\mathrm` as a workaround for now, until we manage to figure out what's going on.